# Laravel Select category Automatically Based on Time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table

**Categories**

- ID
- Name
- Start_time(Timestamp)
- End_time(Timestamp)

I want to show the categories based on time automataically.Like I have categories Breakfast,lunch,dinner etc.I want when user comes to website it will automatically shown that category based on current time.To get current time I am using Carbon api.

To get all categories on main page I am using:

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
     $Foods=Food::paginate(4);
     $now =Carbon::now();
     $Category=DB::table('Categories')
         ->where('Start_time', '<', $now)
         ->where('End_time', '>', $now)
         ->get();
    return view('welcome', compact('Foods','Category'));
}

public function categ($Category_id)
{
   $category = Categories::with('food')->findOrFail($Category_id);
   return view('category', compact('category'));
}
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('/','DetailsController@index');
Route::get('category/{Category_id}', 'DetailsController@categ');
```

**welcome.blade.php:**

```
@foreach ($Category as $categories) 
<button 
style="font-size:14px; width: 230px; height: 30px; background-color: #00A30C; color:white; font-style: italic; text-align: center; font-size: 15px; margin: 0 auto;">
<a  href="category/{{$categories->Category_id}}">{{$categories->CategoryName}} </a></button>

@endforeach
```

But with the above query this return "**[ ]**".How I can get category based on current time?is there any mistake in the query?I am new to laravel plz help me.Thanks

Comment: It seems that you don't have cats that satisfy these conditions. Check your data.

Comment: I have data in my categories table.Also I have added columns in model.

Comment: @AndrejLudinovskov how can I get categories based on current time?

Comment: Well, attach data that you have in database and print the value of $now.

Comment: I don't understand.when I print value of $now it shows me current data and time